# installing Filebeat on windows

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm new Elastic Stack.  I've been able to install Elasticsearch and Kibana via Docker using the instructions on elastic.co.  However, I'm having some difficulty installing filebeats using the directions on elastic.co.  After starting Elasticsearch and Kibana, when I run:

docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.13.0 setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]

I get the following output:

Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200: Get "http://localhost:9200": dial tcp [::1]:9200: connect: cannot assign requested address]

This is with a docker setup.  Any guidance to fixing this would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you were following instructions from [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html) You can see, that it should use the same network.

So instead of

```
docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.13.0 setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]
```

should be

```
docker run --net {network_name} docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.13.0 setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]
```

Check Your elasticsearch container network with following command

```
docker inspect  -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks}}' {es-container-name}
```

If You try to run Kibana+Elastic+Filebeat on Windows, I would suggest writing a dockerfile (or dockercompose) with Your own fileabeat.yml.

Of course, if You run Your elasticserach non-containered, You should use host network, but it's another story.